# Adding ApplicationInsights to Azure Function with Autofac

Tags: azure, azure-functions, autofac, azure-application-insights

I've got an Azure function which I'm adding Application Insights logging to.

It uses autofac to manage the dependencies in a config file, and I have added as follows:

```
  private static void RegisterDependencies(ContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
        {
            containerBuilder.RegisterType<ApplicationInsightsLoggerFactory>()
                .As<ILoggerFactory>()
                .SingleInstance();

 containerBuilder.Register(client => new TelemetryClient(new TelemetryConfiguration("[instrumentation key]"))).As<TelemetryClient>().SingleInstance();

...
```

In Program.cs 'Main', this class is called like this `IocConfig.Configure()`

The function runs with no errors, but the logging is not appearing in Application Insights. Have I missed something in this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You don't to write the DI yourself to get a TelemetryClient. [The built-in DI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2%2Ccmd#log-custom-telemetry-in-c-functions) is already available for you to just get one:

```
public class MyFunctionClass
{

    private readonly TelemetryClient telemetryClient;

    /// Using dependency injection will guarantee that you use the same configuration for telemetry collected automatically and manually.
    public MyFunctionClass(TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfiguration)
    {
        this.telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);
    }
```